# Calling javascript api yet showing in dashboard as Places API Web Service

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps-api-3

I'm not trying to use the Places API Web service yet that's how all of my requests show up on the API console dashboard.  I am trying to use the Javascript api and load the places library.

I'm using this code as I have seen in the examples:

```
<script src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=<MYKEYHERE>'></script>
```

If I disable the Places API Web service, my page stops working.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are using the places libraries in the argument try this `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>`

Answer (score 0):

Quota from calls to the Places Library in the Javascript API is now included in the quota for the Places Web Service.

from [the blog post announcing the change](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com.es/2016/06/building-for-scale-updates-to-google.html):

> 4. We now count Google Maps JavaScript API client-side requests towards the daily limit of the associated web service API.*
>
> `*` Exceptions may apply for implementations that were exceeding new quotas prior to June 22, 2016.